# Is there a way to find the Delphi compiler version?

Tags: delphi, version

I try to find programmatically the version of Delphi compiler(s) installed on my machine.

I'm looking in the registry but without success. I'm using Windows 7-64bits Professional

Comment: Thanks David;
in fact I found the information under
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\CodeGear\BDS\6.0
in key ProductVersion

Comment: with the sample provided here http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com... and informations here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Compiler_Versions, it's quite easy to found which version of the compiler is installed

thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the registry. Look under these keys:

```
HKLM\Software\Borland\Delphi
HKLM\Software\CodeGear\BDS
HKLM\Software\Embarcadero\BDS
```

Under each of those keys you will find subkeys with a version number. For example, Delphi 6 is:

```
HKLM\Software\Borland\Delphi\6.0
```

Delphi 2010 is:

```
HKLM\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0
```

Delphi XE5 is:

```
HKLM\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0
```

Note that this will not guarantee that the installations are in fully working order, mind you.

Also be sure to look in the 32 bit registry view if you are on a 64 bit machine. The registry redirector will take care of that for you if your process is a 32 bit process. But you might get confused when looking under regedit. When viewing in regedit these keys become

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\...
```

@RRUZ has a nice post about this here: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/detecting-installed-delphi-versions/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can take any open-source library having the installer. That already was solved in it one way or another. And you can re-use already tred and tested solution instead of wasting your time on NIH-approach.

For example, you may take `JEDI CodeLib` and look into **jcl\source\common\JclIDEUtils.pas**

- http://JCL.sf.net
- http://github.com/project-jedi/jcl

And the practical example of yousage those functions is the installer itself: **jcl\install\JediInstaller.dpr**